# How can i improve the performance of this oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three database tables which contains large amount of data(6000). I wrote the following query for some operaton which is working fine.

```
UPDATE productlistprice prl SET prl.value = (
    SELECT minprice FROM(
       SELECT  MIN(prl.value) AS minprice, prv.productmasterid AS masterprid 
            FROM product pr , productlistprice prl, productvariation prv 
              WHERE prv.productmasterid = (
       SELECT prv.productmasterid  FROM  productvariation pv 
              WHERE pv.productid = pr.uuid) 
              AND prl.productid = pr.uuid AND prl.productid  = prv.productid 
                    GROUP BY prv.productmasterid) 
              WHERE masterprid = (SELECT prv.productmasterid
              FROM productvariation prv WHERE prv.productmasterid = prl.productid 
                    GROUP BY prv.productmasterid)) 
              WHERE prl.productid = (
       SELECT prv.productmasterid FROM productvariation prv 
              WHERE prv.productmasterid = prl.productid 
GROUP BY prv.productmasterid );
```

But the performance of this query is bit slow. it is taking 21 seconds to update the records. Where can i improve this query. Any suggestions will be greatly appriciated

Comment: How can you even read it? :) What indexes do you have?

Comment: I would start by rewriting your query making use of the `join` keyword.

Comment: @podiluska does join keyword improves the performance ?

Comment: Please use join to improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

Not understanding the underlying datamodel makes this query hard to understand. For example,
I don't understand the where clause of the update statement:

```
update productlistprice prl
   ...
 where prl.productid = (select prv.productmasterid
                          from productvariation prv
                         where prv.productmasterid = prl.productid
                         group by prv.productmasterid);
```

Does it mean you only want to update the records with an ID equal to the productmasterID? And what is the purpose of the group by clause?

For better readability:

```
update productlistprice prl
   set prl.value =
       (select minprice
          from (select min(prl.value) as minprice
                      ,prv.productmasterid as masterprid
                  from product          pr
                      ,productlistprice prl
                      ,productvariation prv
                 where prv.productmasterid = (select prv.productmasterid
                                                from productvariation pv
                                               where pv.productid = pr.uuid)
                   and prl.productid = pr.uuid
                   and prl.productid = prv.productid
                 group by prv.productmasterid)
         where masterprid = (select prv.productmasterid
                               from productvariation prv
                              where prv.productmasterid = prl.productid
                              group by prv.productmasterid))
 where prl.productid = (select prv.productmasterid
                          from productvariation prv
                         where prv.productmasterid = prl.productid
                         group by prv.productmasterid);
```

Comment: productmasterid is the foreign key in the database table so that there exists multiple ids with same, thats why i am grouping them

Comment: And yes, i want to update the records with id equals to productmasterid

Comment: One improvement would be to use "where exists". 
where exists (select prv.productmasterid
                          from productvariation prv
                         where prv.productmasterid = prl.productid)

Comment: if you use join then you don't need to use the group by clause in this query

Comment: @user964147: Hi, did you want update the minimum price in the productlistprice  based on the productmasterid,productId?

Comment: @ThangamaniPalanisamy yes, i want to update the master product with minimum price of its subproducts

Comment: @user964147: UPDATE  prl SET prl.value = MIN(prl.value)
FROM productlistprice prl
INNER JOIN product pr ON pr.uuid = pr1.productid 
INNER JOIN productvariation prv ON  prv.productid  = pr1.productid  
AND prv.productmasterid = prl.productid. Can you try this?

Comment: @ThangamaniPalanisamy: When i execute this query oracle is saying group function is not allowed here